# SOQL 4 level Relationship

Tags: soql, relationships, child-to-parent, outer-join

I am new to SOQL and working with a 4 Level parent - child Relationship:

Level1 (Parent)
Level2 (Child)
Level3 (Grand Child)
Level4 (Great Grand child)

I am trying to pull records from Level1, Level2 & Level4

eg:

```sql
Select Level1_r.Id, Level1_r.date, c.category,(SELECT name FROM Level_3s__r.Level4s__r) FROM Level2_c c
```

This is not working for me, I dont know where I went wrong. It will be great if someone have a solution for this

Comment: What error are you getting when you try this query? It should be possible to go 5 levels, but not more. In fact, there is a [specific error for exceeding the relationship limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm).

Comment: It says Level1_r is invalid. Kindly guide me on syntax

Comment: Well, `Level1_r` with only *one underscore* would be incorrect syntax. You need *two*: `Level1__r`.

Answer (score 3):

What you are mentioned in a question is a parent-to-child relationship. you can go only 1 level deep. So you can't use it here

Let's say, you have `Level1__c`, `Level2__c`, `Level3__c`, `Level4__c` objects with respective lookup fields on parent object.

Option 1

If you need to get `Level4__c` records  you will need to perform the following query, In this way, you are querying data "from child to parent"

**Level4__c** objects by **Level1_c** object id

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Level4__c WHERE Level3__r.Level2__r.Level1__c  = :SOME_LEVEL1_ID
```

**Level3__c** objects by **Level1_c** object id

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Level3__c WHERE Level2__r.Level1__c  = :SOME_LEVEL1_ID
```

**Level2__c** objects by **Level1_c** object id

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Level2__c WHERE Level1__c  = :SOME_LEVEL1_ID
```

or, with one query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Level3__c, Level3__r.Name, Level3__r.Level2__c, Level3__r.Level2__r.Name FROM Level4__c WHERE Level3__r.Level2__r.Level1__c  = :SOME_LEVEL1_ID
```

---

Option 2
Query ids from parent to child and storing it it some variable:

```
Id level1Id = 'SOME_ID';
List<Level2__c> level2Children = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Level2__c WHERE Level1__c = :level1Id];

List<Level3__c> level3Children = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Level3__c WHERE Level2__c IN :level2Children];

List<Level4__c> level4Children = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Level4__c WHERE Level3__c IN :level3Children];
```

Comment: do you mean to say that i cant achieve this in a single query?

Comment: @Amudha yes, please check the examples, that I provided

Comment: Thank you @Oleksandr